# What does "unscrambled" mean in this context?

Tags: x86, x86-64, intel

Can some body please tell me what word **"unscrambled"** means from this manual?

http://www.intel.com/Assets/ja_JP/PDF/manual/253668.pdf

According to the Intel manual, section 5.10.3, explaining the LSL instruction:

> Ff the privilege level and type checks pass, loads the unscrambled
>   limit (the limit scaled according to the setting of the G flag in the
>   segment descriptor) into the destination register and sets the ZF flag
>   in the EFLAGS register. If the segment selector is not visible at the
>   current privilege level or is an invalid type for the LSL instruction,
>   the instruction does not modify the destination register and clears
>   the ZF flag.

Comment: I've updated your title and tags. The manual documents the x86 and x86_64 architectures; it's not related to Linux or Unix.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it's due to the fact that the limit field is spread across several bits within the GDT entry.

The structure of a GDT entry was extended from smaller, earlier versions. Originally, back when protected mode was still only 16-bit, each entry consisted of a single 16-bit base and limit. With the addition of 32-bit mode, there needed to be a way to extend the base/limit without breaking backwards compatibility. Thus, Intel simply added new fields for the upper bits, which causes the base/limit fields to be discontinuous within the entry.

[The OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/File%3aGDT_Entry.png) has a nice little diagram describing a GDT entry; as it shows, the base/limit fields are split up into lower/mid/upper "pieces". So, the "unscrambled" limit refers to the lower/upper limit fields put together into a single 20-bit limit. When the granularity bit is set, it also includes the 4K-multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the G flag, the limit is interpreted in a different way.
From the manual:

```
When the G flag is clear (byte granularity), the effective limit is the value
of the 20-bit limit field in the segment descriptor. Here, the limit ranges 
from 0 to FFFFFH (1 MByte). When the G flag is set (4-KByte page granularity), 
the processor scales the value in the limit field by a factor of 212 (4 KBytes). 
In this case, the effective limit ranges from FFFH (4 KBytes) to FFFFFFFFH 
(4 GBytes).
```